# Select whether cl.t_sc_1=1 OR cl.t_sc_2=1 OR cl.t_sc_3=1 AND column1=10

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS cl.id AS id,
cl.column1 AS column1,
cl.column2 AS column2,
cl.column3 AS column3,
cl.t_sc_1 AS t_sc_1,
cl.t_sc_2 AS t_sc_2,
cl.t_sc_3 AS t_sc_3
FROM classifieds AS cl
WHERE (cl.t_sc_1 = 1 OR cl.t_sc_2 = 1 OR cl.t_sc_3 = 1)
AND column1 = 10 AND column2=10 AND column3=10
ORDER BY cl.id ASC
```

And I want to get results whether(t_sc_1 =1 OR t_sc_2 =1 OR t_sc_3=1) OR the_three_columns=1 AND column1=10 etc, ...I'm getting resluts where t_sc_1 =1 and t_sc_2=1 and t_sc_3 =1 and column1=10 etc instead.
So the rows that have t_sc_1 =1 only or rows that have column3 =1 only are not shown in the results.

The real query is dynamic, sometimes the 'OR' part includes two cl.t_sc_1=1 (like (cl.t_sc_1=1 OR cl.t_sc_2=1)) sometimes inlcudes the three like in the example.

I know whether clause doesn't exist but is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: PROVIDE YOUR CODE

Answer (score 2):

Let's call

```
column1 = 1   as  a
column2 = 1   as  b
column3 = 1   as  c
column4 = 10  as  d
```

What you said you want is:

```
(a + b + c) + (a.b.c.d)
= a + b + c + a.b.c.d
```

Which, using boolean algebra, is equivalent to:

```
a + b + c.(1 + a.b.d)
= a + b + c.1
= a + b + c
```

Meaning this:

```
where (
    column1 = 1
    or column2 = 1
    or column3 = 1
    )
or (
    column1 = 1
    and column2 = 1
    and column3 = 1
    and column4 = 10
    )
```

is equivalent to:

```
where column1 = 1
    or column2 = 1
    or column3 = 1
```

Or:

```
where 1 in (column1, column2, column3);
```

Comment: Can you help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052465/how-do-i-create-procedure-which-does-similar-job-of-my-php-function-optimizatio)

Comment: @Cactux - *Not working* isn't very informative. Please edit your question and provide sample data, expected output and logic behind the output.

Answer (score 1):

Your current query omits some of the logic which you verbally described to us.  Try this instead:

```
select *
from yourTable
where (column1 = 1 or column2 = 1 or column3 = 1) or
      ((column1 = 1 and column2 = 1 and column3 = 1) and column4 = 10)
order by id asc
```

With this logic, a record that had only column2=1 would be returned.

Comment: I'm doing like this:`select *
from yourTable
where (column1 = 1 or column3 = 1) or
      ((column1 = 1  and column3 = 1) and column4 = 10)
order by id asc` But results with only column1=1 or results with column3=1 only aren't shown