# How do I create procedure which does similar job of my php function (Optimization speedup)

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, mariasql

I got table like below

```
mysql> select * from dts;
+----+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Id | key1 | key2 | serial | pr1  | pr2  | pr3  | pr4  | pr5  |
+----+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    1 |      1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    2 |
|  2 |    1 |    1 |      2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|  3 |    1 |    1 |      3 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
|  4 |    1 |    1 |      4 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    3 |
|  5 |    1 |    2 |      5 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    2 |    5 |
|  6 |    1 |    2 |      6 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
|  7 |    1 |    2 |      7 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|  8 |    2 |    2 |      1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    2 |
|  9 |    2 |    2 |      2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 10 |    3 |    2 |      3 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 11 |    3 |    3 |      1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
| 12 |    3 |    3 |      5 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |
+----+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would like to pass key1,key2,db,table and list of fields comma separated to procedure, and would like to search for nonzero values from those fields for the records returned by the select statement, if suppose If I get all fields which are nonzero just break loop and return string back .

What I tried is below using php

```
function show_available($key1, $key2, $db, $table, $conn, $fields=null) 
{

/* Select all fields in argument from db table where key... */
$query = "select ".$fields." FROM $db.$table where key1=$key1 and key2=$key2";

/* Query */
$result = $conn->query($query , MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

/* Output array  */
$out = array();
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
    /* Loop through fields */
    foreach($row as $key => $val)
    {
        /* If val is greater than 0*/
        if($val > 0 ){

            /*Ok we got field which has value greater than 0*/
            $out[$key]=1;   
        }       
    }
    /* If all fields are found ok in so many records where key1=x and key2=x, break loop */
    if(count($out) == count($field_arr))break;
}

/* Return which all fields has value greater than 0 */
return implode(',', array_keys($out));

 }
```

In the same function, I would like to convert into procedure to speedup my task and want to have output like below, how it is possible, please help someone

If I pass `someprocedure(1,1,db,table,'pr1,pr2,pr3,pr4,pr5')` I would like to get output `pr1,pr3,pr4,pr5` because  when `key1=1` and `key2=1`

```
+----+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Id | key1 | key2 | serial | pr1  | pr2  | pr3  | pr4  | pr5  |
+----+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    1 |      1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    2 | - Found pr3,pr5
|  2 |    1 |    1 |      2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|  3 |    1 |    1 |      3 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 | - Found pr4
|  4 |    1 |    1 |      4 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    3 | - Found pr1
```

Similarly for key1=2 and key2=2

```
|  8 |    2 |    2 |      1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    2 | - Found pr1-pr5, break loop and return string
|  9 |    2 |    2 |      2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
```

Expected output

```
# For procedure call expected o/p
key1       key2 fields_non_zero
1           1   pr1,pr3,pr4,pr5

1           2   pr2,pr4,pr5

2           2   pr1,pr2,pr3,pr4,pr5

3           2

3           3   pr1,pr2,pr3,pr4,pr5
```

table dump

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dts`;
CREATE TABLE `dts` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key1` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `key2` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `serial` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `pr1` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `pr2` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `pr3` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `pr4` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `pr5` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `main` (`key1`,`key2`,`serial`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


LOCK TABLES `dts` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `dts` VALUES (1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,2),(2,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0),(3,1,1,3,0,0,0,1,0),(4,1,1,4,1,0,1,1,3),(5,1,2,5,0,0,0,2,5),(6,1,2,6,0,0,0,0,1),(7,1,2,7,0,1,0,0,0),(8,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2),(9,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0),(10,3,2,3,0,0,0,0,0),(11,3,3,1,1,1,0,0,1),(12,3,3,5,0,0,1,1,0);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you asking, the code above appears to pass back that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is aggregation with `max` (or `sum`) with `concat_ws`:

```
select
    key1, key2, 
    concat_ws(
        ',',
        case when max(pr1) <> 0 then 'pr1' end,
        case when max(pr2) <> 0 then 'pr2' end,
        case when max(pr3) <> 0 then 'pr3' end,
        case when max(pr4) <> 0 then 'pr4' end,
        case when max(pr5) <> 0 then 'pr5' end
    ) as val
from dts
group by key1, key2;
```

Produces:

```
key1    key2    val
1       1       pr1,pr3,pr4,pr5
1       2       pr2,pr4,pr5
2       2       pr1,pr2,pr3,pr4,pr5
3       2       
3       3       pr1,pr2,pr3,pr4,pr5
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/VOEVZU61263)

Comment: I want to create procedure, I don't know how to create it in mysql, I can write php function

Comment: @user3637224 - You can either use the above SQL directly or Look at [this official guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html). You can just use the above query in your procedure and return the result.

Comment: But it will not break loop, with lacs of rows it will be slow if we use either sum or max.

Comment: @user3637224 - If you think loops are going to be faster, you are mistaken. Fastest solutions are usually SQL based, not procedural.

Comment: Can I take some more time to check with my data, select count(distinct  key1,key2) is `541665` ? and total count of table is `113441280`

Comment: @user3637224 - Aggregating the whole big table takes time. Why are you querying it all at once? You can look for paginating the query

Comment: Thank you so much, I accept your answer, I will get back to you if I get some more doubts after running on big table

Comment: why did you use max function why not just `par1 > 0` if you use max it will scan all records right ?

Comment: @user3637224 - All the records in the that group (i.e. for that key1 and key2) and No, that won't work for your case as you need a combination of key1 and key2 once and all the nonzero prX concatenated.